# how to save thumbnail created using jquery nailthumb

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, thumbnails, crop

I want to create thumbnail from uploaded photo in `ASP.NET C#`,

for testing I am using `JQuery nailthumb`, and getting result as I want.

here is my code:

JQuery to create and show thumbnail.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nailthumb-container').nailthumb({
        width: 100, 
        height: 100
    });
});
```

Original Image:

```
<img src="Parrot.jpg" title="parrot"/>
```

Thumbnail Image:

```
<div class="nailthumb-container">
     <img src="Parrot.jpg" title="Beautiful Parrot" class="nailthumb-title" />
</div>
```

but problem is that it only displays image, now I want to save that image to folder, if anyone has solution regarding this please share:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JQuery nailthumb` is use client side code to create thumbnails from the image, not for save it, not for manipulation, only for show it.

What you look for is server side code to create thumbnails, nothing to do with javascript and client side - beside maybe some code to manual manipulate and send the results on server to make the final process.

Here is one example of [thumnails creation on code in asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119330/Creating-Website-Thumbnails-in-ASP-NET) but there are too many more if you search on the internet